# Inheritance - Calling methods within methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know the `super()` function allows you to call a parent method from a child class. So in this example:

```
class Exam():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        
    def show(self):
        print("This is from parent method")


class Quiz(Exam):
    def __init__(self, b, a):
        super().__init__(a)
        self.b = b
        
    def show(self):
        print("This is from child method")
        super().show()

q = Quiz('b', 'a')
q.show()

>>> 'This is from child method'
>>> 'This is from parent method'
```

What if I added another method called `get_score` to both the parent and child class like here:

```
class Exam():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        
    def show(self):
        print("This is from parent method")
        print (self.get_score())
    
    def get_score(self):
        return self.a
    
    
class Quiz(Exam):
    def __init__(self, b, a):
        super().__init__(a)
        self.b = b
        
    def show(self):
        print("This is from child method")
        super().show()
        print (self.get_score())
    
    def get_score(self):
        return self.b

q = Quiz('b', 'a')
q.show()

>>> 'This is from child method'
>>> 'This is from parent method'
>>> 'b'
>>> 'b'
```

I can understand why calling `super().show()` in the child class would return `'b'` since I am overwriting the `get_score()` method.

However, is there a way to maintain the integrity of the parent class so that when I do call `super().show()`

I get this instead?

```
>>> 'This is from child method'
>>> 'This is from parent method'
>>> 'a'
>>> 'b'
```

Sorry in advance if this is bad design. Let me know what other alternatives I can take, even if it means I should the name of the method to avoid this kind of collision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use name-mangling, which will prevent the name-collisions in the subclass
:

```
class Exam():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def show(self):
        print("This is from parent method")
        print (self.__get_score())

    def __get_score(self):
        return self.a

    get_score = __get_score


class Quiz(Exam):
    def __init__(self, b, a):
        super().__init__(a)
        self.b = b

    def show(self):
        print("This is from child method")
        super().show()
        print (self.__get_score())

    def __get_score(self):
        return self.b

    get_score = __get_score


q = Quiz('b', 'a')
q.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to get you suggestion on regarding whether name mangling is considered a good practice? Or is there any other way the same problem can be addressed?

Comment: @AnuragReddy it's sole purpose for existing is to prevent name-collisions in subclasses.  The other way is to use another name for the method (which is essentially what name-mangling does). You are overriding the method, can't have it both ways. From this toy example, it's hard to say whether this is bad or not

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Now its much clear to me.

Comment: I suppose I could directly call `super().get_score()` and get the same result but I wanted to obfuscate some of the technical details and allow the user to just a single method that does most of the heavy lifting. Thank you this works. I selected your answer as the best answer! @juanpa.arrivillaga